# Joomla 1.5 + Virtuemart 1.1.5 + Mynxx Theme - $navigation_childlist does not display

Tags: joomla1.5, virtuemart

I'm working on a site for a designer who has set up Joomla 1.5 and Virtuemart 1.1.5 and is using the Mynxx theme.

The requirement is for category pages to display only the first level of subcategories, no products or deeper levels of subcategory. I can achieve the desired affect using the default theme. However, activating the Mynxx theme brings me undone.

I understand it is the $navigation_childlist variable that produces the list of subcategories I'm after. I've found various posts that tell me that I need to echo the variable in the browse_header_category.tpl.php file. However, I cannot get the $navigation_childlist variable to produce anything. I've tried putting it in all sorts of template files to at least get it to display, but no love.

I realise this is likely to be something very simple, possibly just a configuration issue. However, I've been at it for hours and this is driving me nuts.

If anyone could point out the obvious for me I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out for myself, so this is for anyone else that stumbles upon this question/issue.

The answer is:

You're an idiot!!!

I was uploading the changes to the wrong test server. Classic PEBKAC.

So the solution is what I've described in my question, you just need to make the changes to the right server!